# NodeJS - How do I buld a path to a users local /downloads directory from Heroku?

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku

I am downloading images directly from a URL, and it works perfect running locally. However once the application is staged on Heroku, Node can not access a users home directory. It is trying to download the images to a /downloads folder in the apps local directory on Heroku, and since that does not exist, it returns a 400 ENOENT.

Here is the code responsible for saving the images, and finding a users home directory based on their OS:

```
const download = require('image-downloader');
const path = require('path');
const userDownloadDirectory = path.join(require('os').homedir(), 'downloads');

exports.download_image = (req, res, next) => {
  const { body } = req;
  const { imageUrl, gameName } = body;

  const options = {
    url: imageUrl,
    dest: `${userDownloadDirectory}`
  };

  download
    .image(options)
    .then(({ filename, image }) => {
      return res.status(200).send(filename);
    })
    .catch(err => {
      const error = new Error();
      error.message = err;
      error.status = 400;
      next(error);
    });
};
```

This line is responsible for building a path to a users /downloads folder based on their OS:

```
const userDownloadDirectory = path.join(require('os').homedir(), 'downloads');
```

Locally this works perfectly fine. However once on Heroku, this is what it spits out:

```
dest: '/app/downloads'
```

Heroku is building a path to a nonexistent directory (/app tells me it's trying to find this folder within the app directory on Heroku), and as result I get an ENOENT error stating this directory does not exist.

Whereas when I have the app running on my local machine, this is what that line spits out:

```
dest: '/Users/maisonm/downloads'
```

This directory path is to my local downloads folder, which is where I want these images to save.

How can I get Node to build a path to a users downloads folder when it's running on Heroku?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like Heruko resolves `require('os').homedir()` to `/` which can be perfectly valid. 
Personally, I have no experience on Heroku but it looks like it's either running things in containers or masks the user (and the directory obviously).

I think the best solution for you is to configure a proper path to download things to.
Even if `downloads` works for you, I can assure you, it wouldn't work for me (as my downloads directory is called `Downloads`).

So you should just go, create a proper mount and configure your application to save things there.

Btw. if you care for how node [figures out](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/blob/59146f2f4bea7b692238103a8a8e82c4bdc1fc2b/src/unix/core.c#L1085) your home directory, here's how it's done:

1. Reads the `HOME` variable
2. Reads entries in `password` by invoking `getpwuid_r`, return the home dir